# Is there a way to place switch in include?

Tags: php, laravel, switch-statement, laravel-blade

I'm working on my PHP project build on Laravel 5.4 framework. I was wondering if there is a way to place a switch statement into an include call.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@include('components/notification_message/_notification_message_html'
        , [ 'notificationType' => $notificationType
          , 'notificationMessage' => $notificationMessage
          , 'iconType' => switch($notificationType){case 'success': 'check'; break; case 'warning': 'warning'; break; default: 'exclamation';break;}])
```

As you can guess, I got a syntax error after I've tried to run it.
Any idea how I should do this?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `@if` `@elseif` `@elseif` `@else` `@endif` and `@include` inside each. Simplest solution out there. And everyone will understand it from just skimming the code.

Comment: Why not place the switch in `components/notification_message/_notification_message_html`?

Comment: Both ideas are good and I've already tried them and worked. But I was trying to find something fancy. If there is nobody else with a better idea i will mark your answers as good.

Comment: Bunch of `?:` may be e.g. `$notificationType === 'success' ? 'check' : ($notificationType === 'warning' ? 'warning' : ...)`

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @SalmanA can you please post an answer with the content of your comment so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use switch statement like this. You could use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) instead:

```
@include('components/notification_message/_notification_message_html', [
    'notificationType' => $notificationType,
    'notificationMessage' => $notificationMessage,
    'iconType' => $notificationType === 'success' ? 'check' : ($notificationType === 'warning' ? 'warning' : 'exclamation')
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of placing a switch statement inside the include. You can do a straight up switch with includes:

```
@switch($i)
    @case(1)
        @include('...');
        @break

    @case(2)
        @include('...');
        @break

    @default
        @include('...');
@endswitch
```

Or You can use some combination of `@if` directives and/or `includeIf` and `includeWhen`:

`@includeIf('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])`

`@includeWhen($boolean, 'view.name', ['some' => 'data'])`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views